# Batch XML validation with Xerces-C

Tags: xml, validation

I'm setting up a batch validation environment using XML ValidatorBuddy. On creating the batch task I can choose between Xerces-C and Xerces-C SAX parser (among others...). On running the batch for my XML instance documents I get the same results regardless if I take Xerces or Xerces SAX.

I understand that the SAX parser requires less memory and can also validate bigger XML files. However are there any disadvantages to expect if I choose the SAX parser for the scheduled batch validation task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find more information about differences between the Xerces-C SAX and DOM parser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148604/difference-between-dom-parser-and-xerces-parser)

According to the link above in your particular case of XML ValidatorBuddy the only difference will be that using SAX the batch run will use much less memory and should be the preferred parser.